# Sketching a Graph of a Particle Trajectory

Tags: functions, physics, graphing-functions, mathematical-physics

How can I sketch the trajectory of a particle of mass $m$ with a position vector

$\mathbf{r} = \cos(\omega t)\,\hat{\mathbf{i}} + 
\sin(3\omega t)\,\hat{\mathbf{j}}$ ?

Will this be a three dimensional graph, with an $x, y, t$ coordinate system?

Answer (score 1):

This will be a 2-dimensional graph, since the position vector r has 2 components.

Draw an x,y plane. At time t, the x position is $\cos(\omega t)$ and the y position is $\sin(3\omega t)$.

Comment: How do I incorporate the $t$ values into the 2-D graph of $x $ and $y$?

Comment: I agree with @wltrup, label some points on the plot with the t values.